# VNC server on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vnc

I want to have access to a windows 7 using VNC.

Note - RDP is not good for my needs since I need a single session running, and the ability to connect to it from different clients (not at the same time) without interrupting the session to review running processes.

I started with real vnc, and had awful performance.
I moved to UltraVNC using a mirror driver and it's better, but still slow, and the screen refresh is bad (might take 10s of seconds for it).

Does anyone have an idea for improving this?

Comment: I looked for this issue in serverfault.com and found: http://serverfault.com/questions/6386/vnc-on-vista.
This seems to improve the performance.

Comment: Have you tried to use other types of remote desktop providers?

Comment: Hi Steve. No - I haven't. I use VNC for a while, and being free and simple, it works well for me on windows and Linux. Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many options, I found that the suggestion in
[serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/6386/vnc-on-vista)
worked best for me. It tuned VNC to poll changes and the performance is good now.

Answer (score 2):

I found a fresh solution for windows 7 or vista - http://www.onlinevnc.com. It has a good performance and access from web browser support via flash viewer. Works well.